# Why, when I float right, the background color disappears?

Tags: html, css

At the bottom of the page, I would like a yellow bar to go across and have social media links and other small details. I want the links to be on the right and small details to be on the left.

**HTML:**

```
<footer>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.svg" /></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5c300;
}

.one-third {
    float:right;
}
```

As I was writing this, I figured that the .one-third is incorrect for the CSS part and maybe it should be `footer a img {...}`.

Update: No even as I did this ^ it still got rid of the background color of the footer. I then threw a BG color on the footer a img style and it only changed behind the icon, not the whole footer.

Comment: @gayathri no additional code is required. OP has provided enough code to replicate issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you float an element you take it out of the current document flow. What does that mean? Well, as far as container elements are concerned those floated elements don't take up space. If the container element doesn't have any content taking up space (height), then the height of the container is 0 and no background color. Even though floated elements don't take up space, other elements will *"see"* them and flow around them.

How to fix? Clear the float. The most popular method is to use a **clearfix**. A clearfix is typically a CSS class. I use the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) by Nicolas Gallagher.

```css
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<footer class="cf"><!-- floated elements --></footer>
```

Another clearfix solution is to apply `overflow: hidden;` to the element containing floated elements. This has some drawbacks as sometimes you don't want to hide content that overflows the parent.

```css
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5c300;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I threw that into the code and bam. I got my bg color back! Thanks. I will study the clearfix!

Comment: Another question I have if you don't mind, why is it that when you float the elements you push go in reverse order... So I put icons at bottom of page for facebook then instagram, but when you float, facebook will be on the right instead of the left.

Comment: You may find that using `float: left;` might be more appropriate for the element ordering that you're looking for. The browser will float those elements as it comes to them. When you float them to the right, the first `.one-third` DIV gets moved to the right, then the second `.one-third` DIV gets moved to the right and then the third `.one-third` DIV. Effectively reversing the order.

Comment: I guess I don't know the exact layout you're looking for. I'm going off your CSS class names and markup. From what I see you want three columns to take up one third of the footer element's width. But your comments suggest you might be looking for something along [these lines](https://jsfiddle.net/7qrkxm43/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Zmp66hXeiYAhS3VUyl8E?p=preview

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
   <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Basic plunk!</h1>

    <!-- Put your html here! -->
   <div class="footer">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                       <ul class="list-icons">
                                <li>
                                   <a href="">
                                      <em class="fa fa-twitter-square"></em>
                                   </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                   <a href="">
                                      <em class="fa fa-facebook-square"></em>
                                   </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                   <a href="">
                                      <em class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></em>
                                   </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                   <a href="">
                                      <em class="fa fa-instagram"></em>
                                   </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                   <a href="">
                                      <em class="fa fa-flickr"></em>
                                   </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                   <a href="">
                                      <em class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></em>
                                   </a>
                                </li>
                             </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong>Copyright</strong> Example  
                    </div>
                </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and CSS

/* Put your css in here */

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
ul
{
  list-style:none
}
ul li
{
  float:left;
  padding-right:20px;
}
```